# How to check if a service returns no data when using Dojo Cross domain ie dojo/request/script

Tags: javascript, dojo, widget, jsonp

I am using using Dojo to access a webserice and retieve JSONP. Sometimes the service might be down or the service might not return the data. Even though I have an error handler, but if the service does not return any data, I see the widget still tries to create html. I would need help to see what I should do so that id does not return anything.

this is the part of the code I have

```
    script.get(wURL,{
        jsonp: "callback",              

        query: {

            q1:"query1",

            mediatype:"json",


        }
    }).then(function(data){
          //doing something
           },      function(error){
        console.log("An error occurred: " + error);
```

Comment: you can always ask if(data), or something more specific before you render the html...

Comment: Ok, never thought I can do that. Sorry for my ignorance. But the if(data) would work only if there is an issue with the data. What other errors  I should account for?